# How to fix error: could not find the required version of the Java(TM) 2 runtime environment in '(null)' in Windows 8.1 verson

Tags: java

I have downloaded java java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows-x64 and am trying to install it on windows 8, but I am not able to install. I got an error like
could not find the required version of the Java(TM) 2 runtime environment in '(null)',

What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install SDK.

Try downloading any version of Java JDK from - [DownloadJava](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)